# Docker compose: services cannot connect to each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) on docker services and swarms. But I'm having some trouble with networking between different docker containers.

The following is my `docker-compose.yml` file, it basically contains two services. One is just a redis image connected to two networks (although the second is useless for now). And the other is my application which needs to connect to redis. For that reason I opted to give the redis service a static IP.

```
version: "3"

services:
  my_redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      first_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.1
      second_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.30.1.1
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_my_app
    image: my_app_image
    depends_on:
      - my_redis
    deploy:
      replicas: 1 # 4
    networks:
      - first_network

networks:
  first_network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24
  second_network:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.30.1.0/24
```

And the following is my Dockerfile for `my_app`:

```
FROM python:3.7
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
CMD ip a && wait-for-it.sh 172.20.1.1:6379 && PYTHONPATH=. python3 my_app.py
```

Now the problem I'm having is that for some reason, my app cannot connect to the redis service. So I tried the following:

1. I tried running the redis container alone, using the following command: `sudo docker run -p 6379:6379 redis` and then I used [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) to make sure that `localhost:6379` was up and running and it was.
2. I thought then maybe `docker stack deploy` is creating the app service before the redis service, So I added the `depends_on` part in the `docker-compose` file.
3. I found out that even `depends_on` [only guarantees order of starting](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on) (not being ready, i.e. not running all commands before proceeding to next image) and that I have to find [a different solution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/). Based on that I also changed the `Dockerfile_my_app` to run `wait-for-it` before it actually runs my app. Didn't work.
4. Lastly, I didn't know what else to do, I ran `ip a` to see if `my_app` service is getting the right IP. and it is getting an IP in the right range:

   ```
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    | 1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |     link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |     inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    | 1010: eth0@if1011: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |     link/ether 02:42:ac:14:01:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |     inet 172.20.1.3/24 brd 172.20.1.255 scope global eth0
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    | 1012: eth1@if1013: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |     link/ether 02:42:ac:12:00:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |     inet 172.18.0.3/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global eth1
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    |        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for 172.20.1.1:6379
   my_test_my_app.1.jydyydckzyfh@snode-01    | wait-for-it.sh: timeout occurred after waiting 15 seconds for 172.20.1.1:6379
   ```

So in short, IPs are getting assigned correctly. However, the `my_app` service cannot connect to the `redis` service. Is there any reason why? Am I missing something in the compose file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing `wait-for-it.sh 172.20.1.1:6379` in Dockerfile_my_app to:

```
wait-for-it.sh my_redis:6379
```

and see if that works.

Explanation:
If i'm not wrong, once containers are part of the same network, they are able to communicate with each other via the service names declared in the docker-compose file.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/ under 'Networks' and https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for detailed information

Comment: I've added an explanation. I'm no expert on this subject but I've used it before and this is my understanding (:

Comment: Yes, but what I meant is why using the IP doesn't work? If it can resolve the names then theoretically it should be able to connect using the IP directly, right?

Comment: Regardless, a nice side effect of your answer is that I don't really need to assign static IPs.

Comment: yeah let docker-compose handle the assigning of ip addresses internally for you. Regarding why using ip-addresses directly doesn't work, maybe someone else can provide better insight. Cheers.